# Is there no basic mp3 player?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mp3, mp3-player

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4. Previously I could play mp3 files with the "music" application. Now I have 10 players but the plain "music" player is gone and no builtin player can play an mp3 file from my memory card. Why? There used to be a player in the android that could do it. Instead I have google play which seems new.

Comment: It would help, if you add your phone's manufacturer and model, as well as the players you have install, to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most players you need to tell it where to find the music files or have the ap scan the device. i use Music folder player its free and does the trick

Comment: I found a good one (but it had advertising). I'm going to try and find a more basic player if I ask at software recommendations Q&A. Now it seems that there is no builtin audio player and that I must use a tool.

Comment: "In most players you need to tell it where to find the music files or have the ap scan the device." ??? Most music players rely on the media library, which the Android system takes care for (see: [media-scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info)). The only ones you might need to tell where your files are are those for [FolderPlay & AudioBooks](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay). And only very few build up their own library database (so that you must let the app scan the entire device).